# Powershell Array search for keys

Tags: powershell

I Have an array called $a

`echo $a` gives:

```
url                                                               load                                                             
---                                                               ----                                                             
win-coll2.astest.org                                              9                                                                
win-coll.astest.org                                               110                                                              
win-coll4.astest.org                                              110                                                              
win-coll5.astest.org                                              140                                                              
win-coll3.astest.org                                              410
```

now i want to know, if the array contains a sting 
eg:
`win-coll2.astest.org` should lead to `true`
and `win-coll7.astest.org` should lead to `false`

is there a proper way to do this without a `foreach`?

with foreach:

```
$IsInArray = false
$ProofString = "win-coll2.astest.org"
foreach( $item in $a){
  if($item.url -eq $ProofString){
    $IsInArray = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In powershell v4 (and possibly v3) you can do the following:

```
[PS] > $a.url -contains 'win-coll2.astest.org'
True
[PS] > $a.url -contains 'win-coll7.astest.org'
False
```

Otherwise, I think the easiest, least painful way is either do a `foreach` or a `foreach-object`...

Comment: since which WinServ is PS v4 supported? Is it available on 2008?

Comment: I think you need R2, take a look at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855 for more info about it.

Comment: @Joel PoSh v4, through the Windows Management Framework v4 is available on Server 2008 R2, but not Server 2008.